# How do I import a sample table script on SQLite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently trying to learn SQL by reading the SAMS Teach Yourself SQL textbook. I've downloaded a ready-to-use data file for SQLite (obtained from the SAMS Sql website), and it is saved as "tysql.sqlite" in TextEdit format. However, I cannot figure out how to run this sample data file on sqlite3. The book itself offers little to no information about how to get this sample data file to work on sqlite3. How does one import sample table scripts on sqlite3? If anyone can help me solve this beginner's question, I would sincerely appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I supose that you have installed SQLite3. I recomend you that you install a database browser for SQLite. I use [this program](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) (DB Browser for SQLite). When you have this program you only have to open your file (`tysql.sqlite`).